# Coil AsyncImage Software rendering not supported for Pictures that require hardware acceleration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, hardware-acceleration

I'm running into a crash while using `Coil AsyncImage` with hardware acceleration. I've seen that I can use `allowHardware(false)` to resolve the crash, but not entirely sure of where to implment this.

I've also tried setting `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true` to true and false and no difference.

The full crash stack

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering not supported for Pictures that require hardware acceleration

at android.graphics.Picture.draw(Picture.java:187)                                                                                                      at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPicture(Canvas.java:1307)                                                                                                        at com.rob.hotscots.corehome.PostShareViewKt.createBitmapFromPicture(PostShareView.kt:312)                                                                                                      at com.rob.hotscots.corehome.PostShareViewKt.access$createBitmapFromPicture(PostShareView.kt:1)

at com.rob.hotscots.corehome.PostShareViewKt$PostShareView$shareBitmapFromComposable$1.invokeSuspend(PostShareView.kt:76)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@bdfb067, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@ca7ae14, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@40284b2, Dispatchers.IO]
```

This is the code that calls the image.

```kotlin
        AsyncImage(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(300.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            model = Constants().supaBasePhotoURL + imageName + ".jpg",
            placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.smokehill),
            contentDescription = "image of hots post",
            onSuccess = {
                coreDataViewModel.postImageToShare = it.painter
            }
        )
```

This is where the crash is coming from

```kotlin
private fun createBitmapFromPicture(picture: Picture): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        picture.width,
        picture.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
        true
    )

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE)
    canvas.drawPicture(picture)
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem, but I'm not sure if it comes from Coil though.

I found this library that takes screenshots in Compose and it doesn't crash: https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot

It works fine with this library but I can't figure out either why we would get this crash in the first place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).